# Symfony 3.3 - Autowiring Deprecation Guzzle

Tags: php, symfony, dependency-injection, autowired

since i plan to upgrade my Symfony version i want to remove all Deprecations. I cant figure out how to remove my last two errors.

One is

```
Autowiring services based on the types they implement is deprecated since Symfony 3.3 and won't be supported in version 4.0. You should rename (or alias) the "eight_points_guzzle.client.trigger_api" service to "GuzzleHttp\ClientInterface" instead.
```

But in my serivce, i already use the client interface to inject

```
    public function __construct(
    LoggerInterface $logger,
    EntityManagerInterface $em,
    ClientInterface $client
) {

    $this->em = $em;

    $this->logger = $logger;

    $this->rest = $client;

}
```

what that creates is the guzzle client with my client (configured in config.yml)
eight_points_guzzle.client  **.trigger_api**

I am using this bundle : https://github.com/8p/EightPointsGuzzleBundle

Any ideas how to fix that ?

Thank you in advance, 
Greetings Rabbit

Comment: Verify you are using the latest version of GuzzleBundle.  Are you using any guzzle bundle plugins in AppKernel?  The problem might be there.

Comment: Hey, im using  "version": "v7.2.1", thats the latest version available. I dont use any plugins for guzzle.

Comment: I suppose you can try doing what the message suggests and add an alias to your services.yml file.  The trigger_api service id is being generated by the bundle so you can't mess it with.  You could also manually define your service so autowire won't complain.

Comment: Not sure how to implement your first suggestion. I cant add an alias sinice the services.yml file is in the bundle (vendor dir).
If i would add that in my services.yml, it says that its an unknown service since its not loaded then, or am i wrong here ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Short answer: Add the following line in your services.yml of your application:

```
services:
    GuzzleHttp\ClientInterface: "@eight_points_guzzle.client.trigger_api"
```

Note this is in **yaml** format, if you use another, adjust accordingly.

Long answer: Autowiring has changed in Symfony [Autowiring documentation](https://symfony.com/doc/current/service_container/autowiring.html)
Your service has **ClientInterface $client** as dependency, and this dependency is autowired by symfony. Symfony used to autowire this by type, but this is deprecated. Now a service with the interface as its name and alias to the resource to inject has to be defined.

Comment: That worked just fine ! I was able to fix my other deprication the same way. Even though im not totally sure how it works. I thought since symfony 3.3 you have to inject the Interface instead of the service itself :-/

Comment: That works fine, thank you Jannes. Now I wonder what needs to be done if you have more than one Guzzle client defined in your eight_point_guzzle.yaml?