# Symfony4.2 Autowire bundle services

Tags: symfony4, symfony-4.2

I want to autowire bundle service interface in my own services, but I get the error:

```
Cannot resolve argument $slackOauthService of "App\Controller\Panel\Slack\SigninController::afterOauth()": Cannot autowire service "App\Service\Slack\SlackOauthService": argument "$httpClient" of method "__construct()" references interface "GuzzleHttp\ClientInterface" but no such service exists. Did you create a class that implements this interface?
```

My code is:

```
public function __construct( ClientInterface $httpClient, EntityManagerInterface $em ) {
        $this->httpClient = $httpClient;
        $this->em         = $em;
    }
```

If I inject only the entity manager or a service defined by me, everything works fine, but whatever bundle service I try to inject (guzzle, browserkit, jms serializer etc) it does not work.

I have the default symfony services.yaml file defined for web projects:

```
services:
# default configuration for services in *this* file
_defaults:
    autowire: true      # Automatically injects dependencies in your services.
    autoconfigure: true # Automatically registers your services as commands, event subscribers, etc.

# makes classes in src/ available to be used as services
# this creates a service per class whose id is the fully-qualified class name
App\:
    resource: '../src/*'
    exclude: '../src/{DependencyInjection,Entity,Migrations,Tests,Kernel.php}'

# controllers are imported separately to make sure services can be injected
# as action arguments even if you don't extend any base controller class
App\Controller\:
    resource: '../src/Controller'
    tags: ['controller.service_arguments']
```

I am using Symfony4.2.

What is the solution to this problem?

Comment: What if you try to specify the bundle you want to include in services.yaml does that work?

Comment: It does not. If I add GuzzleHttp\: the error is: The definition for "GuzzleHttp\" has no class. If you intend to inject this service dynamically at runtime, please mark it as synthetic=true. If this is an abstract definition solely used by child definitions, please add abstract=true, otherwise specify a class to get rid of this error.

If I add GuzzleHttp\Client\: the error is the same as above.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have played around with this a while ago. Did you import the GuzzleHttp package? If so maybe this will help you:

```php
use GuzzleHttp\Client;

public function __construct()
{
   $this->http_client = new Client();
}
```

Comment: That worked. The question however, is why i can not use DI for this? There must be a catch somewhere...

Comment: @GeorgeOlah maybe this will give you the answer? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47574194/symfony-3-3-autowiring-deprecation-guzzle

Comment: It actually does. I decided to use your solution and create a wrapper service on my App namespace, so I can replace easy the bundle I use. If I want to use anything else for CURL, i only need to replace it in that service. Thank you!